# External commands in AWK

Tags: shell, awk

Is there a way to use Linux shell commands inside awk?
I need to check user existence from a text file (given as)
`username username@emai.com` and write the ones that are not existing users to a new text file as

```
username password username@email.com
```

Currently I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{
for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
    pass='pwgen'
    if(id -u $i | awk '{$1}' > 999) print $1;
    else $i pass $i,'@email.com' >> newusers.txt
}
}' $*
```

I think it should work, but obviously it doesn't. It should create a new password using the alias pwgen (which creates 1 password per use), check wheter $i element in the text file is an existing user by comparing the output of id -u $i | awk '{$1}' to 999 and if it's not over 999, it should append `username password username@email.com` to a text file named newusers.txt.

Comment: It should be a `bash` script calling `awk` and those commands. Not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your awk script it

```
{
for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
    pass=pwgen
    if(id -u $i | awk {ARG1} > 999) print $1;
    else $i pass $i,@email.com >> newusers.txt
}
}
```

where `ARG1` is the first argument passed to the shell script. The first single quote in your shell script starts a single-quoted literal which ends with the second single quote, i.e. after `| awk {`. THe third single quote starts another single-quoted literal which ends with the fourth single quote, etc. If you want to include a single quote, you need to quote it. But here you don't need a single quote in the awk script anyway. A string in awk needs to be written between double quotes.

> ```
> pass=pwgen
> ```

This line of awk code sets the variable `pass` to the value of the variable `pwgen`. Since `pwgen` is not set, `pass` is set to an empty value.

You presumably meant to write `` pass=`pwgen` ``, which is shell syntax to set the shell variable `pass` to the output of the command `pwgen`. But this is shell syntax, not awk, so unsurprisingly it doesn't work in awk. You can read the output of a command in awk with the pipe syntax:

```
pwgen | getline pass;
close("pwgen");
```

You need to close the pipe, otherwise the next time the instruction is executed would read from the same pipe instead of running a new instance of `pwgen`.

> ```
>     if(id -u $i | awk '{$1}' > 999) print $1;
> ```

You can use the `system` function to execute a shell command. The embedded awk command you wrote doesn't make sense. I suspect you wanted to test if the output of `id -u` is greater than 999; that would be

```
if (system("id -u " $i "| awk \x27{exit(!($0 > 999))}\x27"))
```

`\x27` is a way to put a single quote character inside an awk string. But that's really complicated. Instead, read the output of `id -u` into the awk script.

```
id_command = "id -u " $i;
id_command | getline id;
close(id_command);
if (id > 999) print id;
```

> ```
>      else $i pass $i,'@email.com' >> newusers.txt
> ```

I think you meant to write a line to the file. So you need a print command. To put a space between the elements, pass them as separate arguments to `print`. To join two strings together with no whitespace, put the strings next to each other in the awk script with no operator in between (in awk, the null binary operator means concatenation). And as we've already seen several times, use double quotes around strings.

```
    else print $i, pass, $i "@email.com" >>"newusers.txt"
```

There may be other problems with your script, I haven't reviewed it fully.